# Android java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Path must not be empty

Tags: java, android, path, illegalargumentexception

Android java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Path must not be empty. how to solve? I am trying to get the contact's photo. The application keeps crashing. I do not know how to solve it. Tried to Google but still unable to resolve this error. Contacts with no photo set to it are working fine. It's only those contacts with photos set to it are giving errors.

Code:

```
   @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        final Contact c = filtered_items.get(position);
        holder.name.setText(c.name);
      // if(c.photoUri.equals("")){
        if(c.photoUri == null && c!=null){
            holder.image.setImageResource(R.drawable.unknown_avatar);
        }else{

            Picasso.with(ctx).load(c.photoUri)
                    .resize(100, 100)
                    .transform(new CircleTransform())
                    .into(holder.image);
        }
        holder.lyt_parent.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                dialogAbout(c);
            }
        });

    }
```

Log:

```
`FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.example.apple.qs, PID: 32061
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Path must not be empty.
at com.squareup.picasso.Picasso.load(Picasso.java:181)
at com.example.apple.qs.Activity.adapter.ContactListAdapter.onBindViewHolder(ContactListAdapter.java:92)
at com.example.apple.qs.Activity.adapter.ContactListAdapter.onBindViewHolder(ContactListAdapter.java:31)
at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Adapter.onBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.java:5471)
at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Adapter.bindViewHolder(RecyclerView.java:5504)
at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.getViewForPosition(RecyclerView.java:4741)
at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.getViewForPosition(RecyclerView.java:4617)
at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager$LayoutState.next(LinearLayoutManager.java:1994)
at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager.layoutChunk(LinearLayoutManager.java:1390)
at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager.fill(LinearLayoutManager.java:1353)
at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager.onLayoutChildren(LinearLayoutManager.java:574)
at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.dispatchLayoutStep2(RecyclerView.java:3028)
at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.dispatchLayout(RecyclerView.java:2906)    at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.onLayout(RecyclerView.java:3283)
at android.view.View.layout(View.java:16672)
at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5328)
at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onLayout(RelativeLayout.java:1077)
at android.view.View.layout(View.java:16672)
at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5328)
at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.onLayout(ViewPager.java:1695)
at android.view.View.layout(View.java:16672)
at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5328)
at android.support.design.widget.HeaderScrollingViewBehavior.layoutChild(HeaderScrollingViewBehavior.java:122)
at android.support.design.widget.ViewOffsetBehavior.onLayoutChild(ViewOffsetBehavior.java:42)
at android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout$ScrollingViewBehavior.onLayoutChild(AppBarLayout.java:1170)
at android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout.onLayout(CoordinatorLayout.java:814)
at android.view.View.layout(View.java:16672)
at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5328)
at android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout.onLayout(DrawerLayout.java:1187)
at android.view.View.layout(View.java:16672)
at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5328)
at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:573)
at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:508)
at android.view.View.layout(View.java:16672)
at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5328)
at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1702)
at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1556)
at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1465)
at android.view.View.layout(View.java:16672)
at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5328)
at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:573)
at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:508)
at android.view.View.layout(View.java:16672)
at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5328)
at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1702)
at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1556)
at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1465)
at android.view.View.layout(View.java:16672)
at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5328)
at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:573)
at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:508)
at android.view.View.layout(View.java:16672)
at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5328)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performLayout(ViewRootImpl.java:2319)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:2032)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1191)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRun`
```

Answer (score 0):

check your path is null or not before pass Picasso

```
if(c.photoUri != null && !c.photoUri.isEmpty())
{
Picasso.with(ctx).load(c.photoUri)
                .resize(100, 100)
                .transform(new CircleTransform())
                .into(holder.image);  
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

It is strange that Picasso will fail even if you use `.error(R.drawable.image)`. To solve this problem, you should manually check for string emptiness and put some default placeholder if the path for profile photo is empty:

```
if (c.photoUri != null && c.photoUri.isEmpty()) {
   iview.setImageResource(R.drawable.placeholder);
} else {
    Picasso.with(this).load(c.photoUri)
            .placeholder(R.drawable.avatar_gray)
            .error(R.drawable.avatar_gray)
            .into(holder.image);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the image url is not empty.Especially when referencing from firebase.

```
 if (user.getPhotoUrl().isEmpty()) {
          Picasso.with(Profile.this).load(avata).placeholder(avata).into(profile);
        } else {        Picasso.with(Profile.this).load(user.getPhotoUrl()).placeholder(avata).into(profile);
            }
```

Answer (score -1):

Make sure you are providing correct path of your Firebase Storage and correct Storage reference.

Code:

```
StorageReference storageReference = FirebaseStorage.getInstance()
    .getReference()
    .child("storage_path");
```